# How to clear interval in randomly generated function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several functions defined. The setInterval is picking one at random every second. How do I temporarily clear the interval to pause this behavior?

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/NtVBZ/1/

Code:
    function playZoomout() {
        $('.debug').append('1');
    }

```
function playZoomin() {
    $('.debug').append('2');
}

function playPanright() {
    $('.debug').append('3');
}

function playPanleft() {
    $('.debug').append('4');
}

var fns = [playZoomout, playZoomin, playPanright, playPanleft]
setInterval(function () {
    fns[Math.floor(Math.random() * fns.length)]();
}, 1000);

// This isn't working. Probably because the interval above isn't really named?
$('.pause').hover(function(ev){
    clearInterval(fns);
}, function(ev){
    timer = setInterval( fns, 1000);
});
```

Comment: In order to clear an interval, you need to keep track of the interval number which is returned by `setInterval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var fns = [playZoomout, playZoomin, playPanright, playPanleft];
var fn = function () {
    fns[Math.floor(Math.random() * fns.length)]();
}

var myInterval = setInterval(fn, 1000);

$('.pause').hover(function(ev){
    clearInterval(myInterval);
}, function(ev){
    //timer = setInterval( fns, 1000); -> this does not make sense
    myInterval = setInterval(fn, 1000); // this does
});
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NtVBZ/2/)